# upgrade key with fresh install

Tags: windows-7

i purchased a laptop, with windows 7 home premium, and then i wanted to upgrade it. so i purchased windows 7 professional upgrade. and i installed O.S. with that upgrade version disk, but now when i try to activate window, it shows a error message 0xcoo4f061.

how can i activate my windows 7 professional.

Answer (score 2):

[This article](http://www.winsupersite.com/win7/clean_install_upgrade_media.asp) has a few different methods to allow you to activate it, with the easiest being method three.

It's basically just upgrading the upgrade install to the same level. Because windows 7 is already there the upgrade will activate just fine, even though the version you upgraded from wasn't activated.